# Error(8,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INSERT"

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I receive this message after I want to create a trigger. I google it about this error, but I don't find anything. Have any idea?

My trigger look like this:

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER add_disease AFTER INSERT ON Disease
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE Doc
SET DocFile = 'Don't kno'
WHERE IDFile = :new.IDFile;
END;
```

Comment: Maybe that single quote inside the text in the SET clause? you should double the single quote to be able represent it there.

Answer (score 0):

To escape single quotes in SQL, just add a second single quote:

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER add_disease AFTER INSERT ON Disease
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE Doc
SET DocFile = 'Don''t kno' //This was your problem.
WHERE IDFile = ':new.IDFile;' //Also, I'm guessing this needs to be in single quotes, as well - not sure if the semicolon is part of the value to which you're comparing, but, if not, just remove it.
END;
```

Comment: Thank. I modified there, but I  still had the error. The problem was to that INSERT because the correct form was AFTER UPDATE ON, after I make this modification, my trigger worked. Thanks anyway for you answer.